# What are the discrete valuation rings for the affine plane?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, valuation-theory, dimension-theory-algebra

Let $X = \mathbb{A}^2_k$ be the affine plane over an algebraically closed field $k$, and let $K = k(x,y)$ be the field of rational functions over $X$. How can one describe all discrete valuation rings $R$ with quotient field $K$, please?

In particular, is there a valuation associated with any maximal ideal $(x-a,y-b)$? How is it defined, please?

I am reading Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry", but so far in the book, the author only uses discrete valuation rings $R$ having $\dim(R) = 1$. Is that necessarily so?

Some comments from experts will be appreciated.

Edit 1: It turns out (see KReiser's answer below) that DVR must have dimension $1$. So, at least for "nice" function fields, valuation rings correspond to subvarieties of codimension $1$.

Edit 2: In the comments below KReiser's answer, I was essentially looking at the valuation on the function field of the affine plane blown-up at the origin corresponding to the exceptional divisor. I think my example is interesting. It is a discrete valuation on $k(x,y)$ whose corresponding valuation ring is *not* a localization of $k[x,y]$, unlike what one may conjecture (unless I am mistaken somewhere). It is related to the fact that the affine plane and its blow-up at the origin are birational, and so have isomorphic function fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valuations correspond (under some niceness assumptions) to subvarieties of codimension one, so you will not be able to find a valuation corresponding to $(x-a,y-b)$. With some quick checking (say on wikipedia, stacksproject, any good commutative algebra book), you will find that all DVRs have Krull dimension one.

---

**Edit**: the above answer is incorrect. I'm not sure why I didn't correct this earlier, but the full solution is that every valuation ring of $k(x,y)$ trivial on $k$ is of one of three types (per Hartshorne exercise II.4.12(b)):

- $k(x,y)$
- The generic point of some irreducible curve in a blowup of $\Bbb P^2$ (including the trivial blowup, $\Bbb P^2$)
- Take a sequence of points as follows: pick $x_0\in\Bbb P^2$, blow it up to get $X_1$, pick a point $x_1$ on the exceptional fiber over the blowup, blow that up to get $X_2$, pick a point $x_2$ on the exceptional fiber over the blowup, repeat off to infinity. Then the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X_{i+1},x_{i+1}}$ dominates $\mathcal{O}_{X_i,x_i}$ and the union of all of these is a valuation ring.

The example Malkoun found is of the second type: it's the valuation associated to the generic point of the exceptional divisor of the blowup at the origin. As one can see [here on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12717/points-and-dvrs), valuations can get tricky, and I'm sorry for leaving something misleading up for so long.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: I have a stupid question. Suppose we define $v(g)$, where $g$ is a non-zero element of $k[x,y]$, to be the largest $n$ such that $v(g) \in (x-a,y-b)^n$, and then $v(f/h) = v(f) - v(h)$ for a non-zero element $f/h \in k(x,y)$, where $f,h \in k[x,y]$ and both are non-zero. Why is this not a discrete valuation on $K = k(x,y)$?

Comment: I meant in my 2nd sentence, "...such that $g \in (x-a,y-b)^n$...".

Comment: Pick $a,b=0$ to make things easier. Clearly $v(x)=v(y)=1$, so $v(x/y)=0$ should hold. But this implies that $x/y$ should be in the ring of integers of this valuation, which is clearly nonsense.

Comment: sorry, one last thing. Can you please state the proposition you are using? So you are saying that my $v$ cannot be a discrete valuation on $K$ such that $\{v \geq 0 \} \cup \{0\}$ has as quotient field $K$. However, I cannot directly see which property does not hold. I will think about it later. Thank you.

Comment: This is one of the many equivalent definitions of DVRs. See #10 at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring or https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00I8 for more on valuation rings.

Comment: The thing that's going wrong here is that $x/y$ is not in the localization of $k[x,y]$ at the point $(0,0)$ - remember, we're inverting elements that evaluate to something non-zero when we construct that localization.

Comment: I may be wrong but, if you consider the blow-up map $p$ from the affine plane blown-up at the origin, denoted by $\hat{X}$, to the affine plane $X$, then isn't my valuation $v$ applied to a rational function $a/f$ on the plane essentially the order of the proper transform (I think this is what it is called) of $a/f$ to $\hat{X}$ at the generic point of the exceptional divisor?

Comment: I think my example is interesting. It is a discrete valuation on $k(x,y)$ whose corresponding valuation ring is *not* a localization of $k[x,y]$, unlike what one may conjecture (unless I am mistaken somewhere). It is related to the fact that the affine plane and its blow-up at the origin are birational, and so have isomorphic function fields. My example corresponds to the exceptional divisor in the blow-up.

Comment: KReiser, do you agree with my last paragraph please? After all, the properties of a valuation seem to be satisfied.

Comment: Yes, you've found something here. It's known (see Hartshorne exercises II.4.12, V.5.6) that there's some chicanery with valuations in higher dimensions - this is one of the reasons that their use changes after we leave curves for higher-dimensional settings. Emerton's post at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12717/points-and-dvrs may help with understanding.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.